# Can Chat be added to the apps?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

It would be nice to have the ability to check in the chat rooms via chat. I personally would use this frequently if available, and I'm sure others out there would as well.

Comment: on android [chatsey](http://stackapps.com/questions/4659/chatsey-an-android-app-for-se-chat) is a fairly nice, polished option.